# Is there a way to split Flink tasks in cluster gui besides using .startNewChain()?

Tags: apache-flink

The Flink Cluster's GUI is really beneficial to me, particularly the plan of the job so that you can see the number of records sent from what part of the job to the other. But an issue that I have come across is that if you don't use .startNewChain() in between functions, the data that is said to be sent from one function to another is misleading.

To give an example:

Here, the code is using .startNewChain() on the finalErrorOutputStream.
[image: Code using .startNewChain() for finalErrorOutputStream]

When this is ran in the cluster, the gui displays this:

[image]

The outputDataStream has output 10,476 records and the finalErrorOutputStream is shown as a separate task(not sure if "task" is technically the right term, but it is what I am calling it) that shows it has received 8,860 records.

Now if we remove the .startNewChain() from the finalErrorOutputStream, we get this in the gui:

[image]

The outputDataStream has output 10,507 records and we don't know how many of those have gone to the finalErrorOutputStream (yes, we could set up graphs in the task metrics tab, but the goal is to just be able to tell from this standard overview) and because there is a sink for finalErrorOutputStream, it shows like finalErrorOutputStream hasn't output any records. If you were to show this to someone unfamiliar with Flink and the reasoning for this it would be confusing.

So using .startNewChain() is a better solution to show the breakdown of how many records went to where, BUT the issue is that .startNewChain() does cause a performance impact.

And there are some jobs that I have seen made where if you don't use .startNewChain() it is just a single square in the job's plan even though a lot is going on inside of it.

So my question is if .startNewChain() is the only way to get this behavior or if there is some other option that will provide that insight into the job's "plan"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no other way. The GUI, and the backing data-structures it reads the data from, are only aware of tasks (you used the right term), not operators (the individual parts of a task).